# URL keyword searches in GNOME 3

Tags: gnome, search

I'm trying to find something in GNOME 3 to support keyword based searches. For example, I want to enter "yt car boys" in the system search dialog, and have it bring up `https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=car+boys` in the default web browser.

I got addicted to this in, I think KDE 2, and have been using QuickSilver & Alfred for it on macOS.

Is there something out there which does this for Gnome?

Answer (score 0):

### From the CLI

First of all, it's easy to do something like this from the command line. You can define a function like this one (put the following in your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or whatever file your shell sources at startup):

`yt () { xdg-open "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$*" }`

And you can call it this way from a terminal running your shell:

`yt car boys`

### From an app runner

If you want to emulate the behavior of Quicksilver or Alfred, you want to use an app runner. I suggest you check out [gmrun](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gmrun/) because of how easy it is to make extensions for it.

Add the following line to the file `~/.gmrunrc`:

`URL_yt = xdg-open 'https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%s'`

Launch `gmrun` and input the following:

`yt:car boys`

In both cases, `xdg-open` will launch your default web browser to the desired webpage. It should be fairly easy to adapt these instructions to any website you want.